# Tree Houses for Settlement Defense

Tags: fallout-4

How can you protect your settlers and not just the ones you meet early in the game?

I have tried tree houses, and I'd like people's help advising me. At the Castle, I have built a radio tower tree house of a sorts. Beds, stations, artillery, and turrets raining down on beasties. I haven't seen anything more than a raider so far though.

Will cutting off the stairs to the ground keep them safe from mobs and dreaded death claws? Will it protect my property: turrets, walls, etc?

Comment: I... what? What are you asking? It's difficult to figure out what you're asking without any proper grammar and sentence structure. Even then, you're asking more than one question within a single post.

Comment: He's asking for people to add him on ps4. Which is not a question.

Comment: I said how I'm setup. And I'm asking is building high and putting all I can there cut off from the ground going to protect me overall

Comment: Lots of words, very little said.  As per Kevin, this whole question can be reworded as "add me ps4 id kthxbye".

Comment: @Nelson That seemed like an inconsequential note at the end from a new user. I think I pulled the question out of there. It's about using elevated structures for defense.

Comment: Do your settlers actually stay up in the treehouse?

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden There's a lot in there beside what is essentially a signature at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Settlers don't always stay where you last saw them. I think they respawn at random locations in a settlement when you return, so there is no guarantee that they will stay in the prison you've made for them.

The likelihood of a settlement being attacked, and the type and number of attackers, is related to how much food and water it produces, and how well defended it is. If you aren't growing any food in your treehouse and it is well defended by turrets then you might not get attacked often. If you do get attacked I don't know if having all your crafted stuff out of reach makes it invulnerable to damage. Attackers have ranged weapons, so I would expect them to at least shoot at the turrets.